# Should I say "I miss you today when I drop by your office"?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to write a note to a person that I could not find him at his office, but he does not expect that I would be there

If I write "I miss you today when I drop by your office"

Does it sound reasonable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your sentence would be better in the **past tense**, because it describes an action that took place in the past.

> I miss**ed** you today when I drop**ped** by your office.

This sentence sounds reasonable to me.

Of course, *miss you* has another meaning: **to regret someone's absence**.  And that meaning expresses an emotional attachment that may be inappropriate for this situation.  So even though I think *miss* is okay, you could say it another way to avoid any misunderstanding:

> I drop**ped** by your office today while you **were** out.

I think that would work.

Comment: Using "missed" would normally be OK unless there were circumstances where there could be a possible confusion; @snailboat gives an excellent alternative. However, "miss" in the present tense can easily be misconstrued unless the reader realises that English is not your first language.

Comment: You could also say, "I dropped by your office, but we missed each other."